# Does "by 2014" include the year of 2014, or not?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

In the following sentence, is the company trying to achieve its goal by the end of 2014 or by the beginning of 2014?

> The company aims to acquire one million customers by 2014.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["within this year" vs "by the end of this year"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/within-this-year-vs-by-the-end-of-this-year)

Comment: I wouldn't call that question a "duplicate" (it specifically includes "by the end of"; this one explicitly omits "by the end of"). Related? Sure. Duplicate? I don't think so.

Comment: @J.R.: I don't see any difference. In both cases, ***by** [some specified time]* simply means *when we reach that specified time*. Obviously, we reach 2014 on Jan 1st, not Dec 31st.

Comment: @Fumble: "the end of [some year]" is a specified time. [Some year] is not a specified time, but a year-long chunk of time, and that is what this question is asking about. When the specified time is a year long, "by" is ambiguous, because it could mean "by the start of the specified time," or "by the end of the specified time," or even "by sometime in the middle of the specified time span."

Answer (score 1):

The beginning, since we're talking about an entire year. If we mean the end of 2014, we'll say by the end of 2014.

Comment: I think that you're right, in the general sense. However, in the O.P.'s sentence, I could see that meaning the company wants to acquire one million customers _sometime in_ 2014 – not necessarily just before the end of the year, but sometime that spring or summer would still make management happy. The would almost assuredly be the case if the remark was uttered in late November of 2013, and there was still 150,000 customers to go. So, the meaning of _by_ can be a little bit context-dependent.

Comment: Yes, I struggled a bit with qualifying my statement, got into talking about the differences between "by tomorrow", "by Saturday" and so on, and abandoned it all as too complicated to be of much use.  (Your explanation is better than mine was.)  On the other hand, if I were a CEO making that statement, I wouldn't allow for that wiggle room.  Human nature being what it is, I would understand "sometime in 2014" or "by 2014" to mean precisely the same thing as "by the end of 2014" with respect to the results I would get.  If I wanted "by 2014" to mean by 1/1/2014, I would say "by the end of 2013."